# Refactor a reference variable in part of code in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring, rename

How would I go about renaming a variable in only part of the code?

For example:

```
System.out.println("Rectangle 1: " + "\n" + "Width: " + r1.width + "\n" + "Height: " +
        r1.height + "\n" + "Color: " + r1.color + "\n" + "Area and Perimeter: " + 
                r1.getArea(r1.width, r1.height) + ", " + r1.getPerimeter(r1.width, r1.height));
```

So if I want to type out the same for a second rectangle using r2 as the refVar, is there a way I can quickly do this? I tried copy and pasting then using Alt + Shift + R, but, it ends up changing all of the r1 refvars.

Comment: Why don't  you create another rectangle object?

Comment: Is creating separate method which could produce this output for passed Rectangle an option? Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

Comment: I have another object for r2, it's just I want to print their details out. Should I just use a toString() method that returns all the objects fields in one string?
edit: @Pshemo yeah, I guess i'll do that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take a look at [don't repeat yourself (DRY)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle which was designed to prevent situations like yours. Instead of renaming variables create separate method which will accept any Rectangle and print its details.

```
public static void printRectangleDetails(Rectangle r){

    System.out.println("Rectangle 1: " + "\n" + "Width: " + r.width + "\n" + "Height: " +
            r.height + "\n" + "Color: " + r.color + "\n" + "Area and Perimeter: " + 
                    r.getArea(r.width, r.height) + ", " + r.getPerimeter(r.width, r.height));
}
```

Now you can use it with your `r1` and `r2` rectangles when needed

```
printRectangleDetails(r1);
...
printRectangleDetails(r2);
```

---

If for some reason where you can't create separate method and use DRY principle you can do something like this:

lets say we have

```
String foo = "foo";
System.out.println(foo+" hello wordls"+ foo);

String bar = "bar";
System.out.println(foo+" hello wordls"+ foo);
```

and you want to replace `foo` in second print statement to `bar`. Using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (or from menu: `Refactor` -> `Rename..`) on second printing statement would rename all `foo` references . To prevent it redeclare your `foo` reference (compiler will give you error, but don't worry, we will later remove it, it is helpful only while renaming process) just before statements from which you want to change `foo` to `bar` like

```
String foo = "foo";
System.out.println(foo+" hello wordls"+ foo);

String bar = "bar";
String foo = "whatever";
//     ^^^
System.out.println(foo+" hello wordls"+ foo);
```

Now use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> on this new duplicate `foo` and eclipse will look for `foo` from this new reference, and ignore earlier `foo`s, so you should be able to see something like

[image]

(as you can see first two `foo` are not selected for renaming)
so you can change it to `bar` like

```
String foo = "foo";
System.out.println(foo+" hello wordls"+ foo);

String bar = "bar";
String bar = "whatever";
System.out.println(bar+" hello wordls"+ bar);
```

and after that just removed this additional `String bar = "whatever";` since you don't need it any more.

BUT BE CAREFUL. This way you will rename all `foo` variables after duplicate `foo`, not only those in `System.out.println(foo+" hello wordls"+ foo);` which you wanted to rename. To make sure you are not changing anything you don't want to, place code you want to change at the end of your method (where you are sure there is no `foo` which shouldn't be changed after it). After you are done move your changed code to place you want.

Comment: If feel, Overiding toString method will be a better option, if it is just to print out the result.

Comment: @user2900314 Well, it depends. In general we override toString to create very short description of object which could be used in logs and error messages, and we create separate methods to generate more descriptive output/String. But yes, if OP can update Rectangle class, then adding this method to it would be better then creating one in some other class.

Comment: User may not interested in extracting ONLY few lines(Here 3 lines) of code to a method.

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK DRY principle describes what SHOUDL be done in situation like this, it has nothing to do with wanting to do it or not. Remember that another general rule of good code is not to create very long methods (their body should be visible entirely on one screen) so use "divide and conquer" whenever you feel it can be used to make code more readable, which in this case `r1.printDetails();` or `printRectangleDetails(r1)` does.

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK I updated my answer to cover case where OP can't create new method (lets say company forbids it for some reason). Take a look and say if that covers the case you were interested in.

Comment: @PShemo Tested your snipped but NOT working for me. Once we declare **foo** twice compiler gives an error and Alt + Shift + R NOT works. Additionally I agree that methods should not be too long BUT at the same time methods should not be too short also, Some compiler makes method inline if found very short to avoid extra CALL and RETURN instructions.Here we have only one statement(Sytem.Out.Println) in a method

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK I updated my answer a little to include screenshot showing that this solution should work regardless compilers error (and it works for me on Eclipse Kepler and all earlier versions). Could you describe how does it not work for you: you don't see rename option (maybe try from menu: `Refactor` - `Rename..` ) or it affects all `foo` references (did you set cursor on `foo` we want to rename?).

Comment: Regarding coding style: IMHO  if code fragment is used more then once and with different variables there is nothing wrong with making it a method. Inlining code by compiler is its functionality and thanks to it we can focus more on creating code readable for humans, not machines (let compiler do their job and optimize it for you).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use **Find/Replace** dialog for this problem it suites for your need. Select a set of statements then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>. A Find/Replace dialog will popup, note that in **Scope** group **Selected lines** option is selected.

You can use **Replace All** or **Replace/Find**. But be careful that it also replaces the string in comments if found.

Refer picture below.

[image]

Comment: As you mentioned this method is unsafe because there may be false positive results and `r1` can be changed in many unwanted places. In this case OP would have to iterate manually using this tool over all search results and choose if it should be changed or not. I believe that OP is trying to avoid it and is looking for a way/tool to do it automatically, not manually.